# How to get Json.NET to serialize empty XML element to empty string

Tags: c#, json, json.net

The [release notes](https://json.codeplex.com/releases/view/121470) for Json.NET 6.0 Release 3 states

> Change - Blank XML elements will be written as an empty string instead
>   of null

but this is not my experience.

```
var xmlText = @"<document xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" Version=""1.1"">
                    <empty/>
                    <space> </space>
                    <null xsi:nil=""true""/>
                </document>";
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlText);
var jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
```

I expected

```
"empty":"", "space":" ", "null":{"@xsi:nil":"true"}
```

but got

```
"empty":null, "space":"", "null":{"@xsi:nil":"true"}
```

The lost space is not a problem right now but I really like empty XML elements to be serialized as "" instead of null. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

You'll get what you want if you write the xml in the following format:

```
var xmlText = @"<document xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" Version=""1.1"">
                <empty></empty>
                <space> </space>
                <null xsi:nil=""true""/>
            </document>";
```

As you can notice the node you want to be serialized as empty string is written as `<empty></empty>` instead of `<empty />`.

The thing is that JSON.NET, for serializing xml nodes to json, uses the `XmlNodeConverter` class which in its `SerializeNode` method checks the `IsEmpty` property of the `XmlElement` class. You can read more about this property [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.isempty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The code segment of the mentioned method that decides whether `null` or empty string is serialized, looks like this:

```
if (element.IsEmpty)
    writer.WriteNull();
else
    writer.WriteValue(string.Empty);
```

When the xml fragment is self-closed (`<empty/>`), the `IsEmpty` property returns true and null is written in the json string, otherwise (`<empty></empty>`), it returns false and string.empty is written in the json string.

**UPDATE 1:**

This update should solve the problem described [here](https://gist.github.com/jonelf/47e3a1b2f06b66983e29). (The link is also available in the comments of this answer).

To be able to serialize a property that doesn't have value as `<empty></empty>` instead of `<empty/>`, we should perform custom xml serialization, so the `Serializetest` class (available in the link above) should look like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class Serializetest : IXmlSerializable
{
    public Serializetest()
    {
        Empty = string.Empty;
    }

    public string Empty { get; set; }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("Empty");
        writer.WriteValue(Empty);
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
}
```

Then the main method:

```
var serializetest = new Serializetest();
string xmlText;

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Serializetest));
using (var textWriter = new StringWriter())
{
    using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, serializetest);
    }

    xmlText = textWriter.ToString();
}

var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlText);
var jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);

var json = JObject.Parse(jsonText);
var empty = (string)json.SelectToken("Serializetest.Empty");
// This should return empty string instead of null.
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the standard .NET XML serializer produces </empty> from an empty string property but I will have to get back on that tomorrow.

Comment: Yes, but you can override the XML Serialization to get it work as you need combined with JSON.NET.

Comment: The problem described in code.

https://gist.github.com/jonelf/47e3a1b2f06b66983e29

Comment: That would work if we were in control of the XML serialization but we are not.

Comment: The answer solves the issues described in the question and the additional link, it cannot solve any issues in a project :)

Comment: I appreciate your help. The problem is that your answer requires a change of the XML. It might have been a little unclear but what I really was asking, was for a way to make Json.NET serialize <element/> as {"element":""}.

Comment: That's also contained in the answer. It is not possible with JSON.NET, because of the way `XmlNodeConverter` class handles the empty nodes.